# SELECT COUNT all rows and return just 10 + and a counted total

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to get is to send a request to DB that will:

1 count all rows
 2 return 10 rows

```
SELECT count( * ) AS 'total'
FROM stuff
WHERE usr = '65'
LIMIT 10
```

So it is supposed to return 10 results PLUS 'total' with the number of all rows.
So far it returns the counted amount of rows only....

Comment: not possible. you cannot mix aggregate functions with "normal" data like that. easier to run two separate queries.

Comment: if you set a limit of 10, why do you need to count it?

Comment: @KyleMassacre COUNT isn'T affected by the LIMIT clause, it always counts all rows.

Comment: @KyleMassacre  - I need ALL rows in table to be counted but ONLY 10 to be returned... anyway - looks like it's not posisle in one go... =(

Comment: To expand on what MarcB said, the basic problem is that your `stuff` table has multiple columns, and those columns are incompatible with just a single integer like `COUNT` returns. A `UNION` might have been feasible if the columns were compatible types in both queries.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- count records first
SET @total = (
    SELECT count( * ) AS 'total'
    FROM `stuff`
    WHERE `usr` = '65'
);

-- then, select your ten records and include the total from previous operation
SELECT *, @total
FROM `stuff`
WHERE `usr` = '65'
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to split the 2 concerns out, and then recombine them:

```
SELECT s.col1, s.col2, s.col3, x.total
FROM `stuff` s
CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT count(*) AS total
   FROM `stuff`
   WHERE `usr` = '65'
) x
WHERE s.`usr` = '65'
LIMIT 10;
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42b955/1)
RDBMs like SqlServer and Oracle allow for CTE's which would allow you to DRY up the repeated `select ... where`. Some options in [MySql here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: +1. But, this seems to be duplicate, please find the similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703453/count-rows-in-mysql-along-with-the-actual-row-contents

Comment: Hmm. I agree as it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows to be counted and limit the result to 10 then you can do it the following way

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `stuff` WHERE `usr` = '65' LIMIT 10 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```